# How to perform a __all_in query with Django?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have three models

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Order(models.Model):
    must_have_toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

I want to find all Orders that match a certain Pizza.
For this, I would like to do something like

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(must_have_toppings__all_in=my_pizza.toppings)
```

### What I tried:

`orders = Order.objects.filter(must_have_toppings__in=my_pizza.toppings)` doesn't work, because Orders with just one of the Pizza's toppings in their must_have will be returned.

And:

```
orders = Orders.objects
for topping in my_pizza.toppings.all():
    orders = orders.filter(must_have_toppings=topping)
```

doesn't work, because it will return orders that have all the toppings from the pizza, even if some of the `must_have_toppings` are missing. For example, a Pizza with Tomatoes and Mushrooms will return an Order that needs Tomato, Pepper, and Mushroom.

**How can I look for Orders where the must_have_toppings are ALL in the Pizza object?**

(I am using MySql)

Comment: What if the order has *more* toppings than the pizza?

Comment: Then the order is not returned. All the must_have have to be on the pizza.

Comment: and what if the pizza has more toppings than the order? Is it an *exact* match, or a *subset* match?

Comment: It's okay if the pizza has more. It's just "all the order's must_have_toppings are on the pizza". That's why I think an *__all_in* query would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find orders where all the `Topping`s in an order belong to `my_pizza`, we can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Q

toppings = my_pizza.toppings.all()

Order.objects.annotate(
    ntoppings=Count(
        'must_have_toppings',
        filter=Q(must_have_toppings__in=toppings)
    ),
    total=Count('must_have_toppings')
).filter(
    ntoppings=F('total')
)
```

We here first fetch all the toppings of `my_pizza` and then check if the number of toppings i the same as the number of toppings that belong to `my_pizza`, if that holds, we know that all toppings of the order are a member of that pizza.

We can also do the opposite and check if all toppings of the `my_pizza` belong to the `Order`:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

toppings = my_pizza.toppings.all()
ntoppings = len(toppings)

Order.objects.annotate(
    ntoppings=Count(
        'must_have_toppings',
        filter=Q(must_have_toppings__in=toppings)
    )
).filter(
    ntoppings=ntoppings
)
```

If an `Order` has more toppings than the pizza, than that order will still show up. So if the pizza has as toppings cheese and pineapple, than an order with cheese, salami and pineapple will match.

For an exact match where the order and `my_pizza` have exactly the same toppings, we can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

toppings = my_pizza.toppings.all()
ntoppings = len(toppings)

Order.objects.annotate(
    ntoppings=Count(
        'must_have_toppings',
        filter=Q(must_have_toppings__in=toppings)
    ),
    total=Count('must_have_toppings')
).filter(
    ntoppings=ntoppings,
    total=ntoppings
)
```

All code snippets assume that a topping can only occur once.

Comment: I think `ntoppings__lte=ntoppings, ntoppings=total` is what OP wants. So the number of must haves in the order available on the pizza (let's say navailable) must be less than or equal to the toppings on pizza and the navailable must be equal to the total.

Comment: nvm, your right, if we want to find orders where all the toppings are all in the toppings, then `ntoppings` should be equal to `total`.

Comment: I couldn't get this piece of code to work because I was doing `Order.objects.filter(must_have_toppings__in=toppings)` first. It turns out that if you add this line, it will cause `total=Count('must_have_toppings')` to only retun the number of `must_have_toppings` that are in `toppings` and ignore the others. That's a very strange behavior...